# Object not being passed to HTML file not being printed on Webpage

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I am trying to print the username of the logged in person on my webpage and it is not printing the username. It just says *Welcome,*. I receive no errors in my console or on the web browser console

Do I need to use the Principal class instead or try to retrieve the username from somewhere else? What else could I be missing? Sorry if the questions aren't so great I am still learning on what proper questions to ask.

Here is my method also my UserModel class does have the proper getters and setters.

```
    @GetMapping("/products")
    public String getProducts(Model model, UserModel userModel) {
        List<ProductModel> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        model.addAttribute("person", userModel.getUsername());
        return "products";
    }
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Products</title>
    <!-- Add any necessary CSS or JavaScript files -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <h2>Welcome, <span th:text="${userModel.Username}"></span></h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Availability</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Use Thymeleaf to iterate over the list of products -->
            <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
                <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.availability}"></td>
                <td>
                    <a th:href="@{/productDetails/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Details</a> |
                    <a th:href="@{/updateProduct/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Update</a> |
                    <a th:href="@{/deleteProduct/{id}(id=${product.id})}">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <p><a th:href="@{/createProduct}">Create Product</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Also when I run in debug mode and put a break on  `model.addAttribute("person", userModel.getUsername());` it tells me **0x000000080036c000.invokeVirtual(Object, Object, Object, Object) line: not available**

Comment: Have you tried adding a new UserModel as attribute with the the username of a Principal object as parameter ?

Comment: Yes when I tried using the Principal object I kept getting errors of "template not found" if I remember correctly even though they were in the correct directory. I'm guessing there is more setup if have to do if I use the principal object.

Comment: As I remember, you should also put on your post "thymeleaf". Nb is that jsp and beans also?

Answer (score 1):

In html you need to access username using the same attribute name you added the username to in the controller. i.e.

Replace

```
<h2>Welcome, <span th:text="${userModel.Username}"></span></h2>
```

With

```
<h2>Welcome, <span th:text="${person}"></span></h2>
```

Also make sure userModel.getUsername() in the controller has a value. If it doesn't you can add a dummy username to confirm it's passed to html. Eg

Replace

```
model.addAttribute("person", userModel.getUsername());
```

With

```
model.addAttribute("person", "John Doe");
```

Comment: So I made the changes and they did not work, but when I put in "John Doe" it did say Welcome, John Doe. SO I know that it is at least passing the info to the template. I changed my code and added ```String user = userModel.getFirstName();``` then did ```model.addAttribute("person", user());``` and had it print on my console and it just says ```null```. So I am maybe not pulling the information from the correct area? Would it help to see my UserRepository class?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going a different route and found the HttpSession class and was able to implement that into my code since I do not need beefed up security features yet like the Principal class provides. My loginUser method was also not storing the name of the user like it should of. Here is the code I implemented.

```
    public String getProducts(Model model, HttpSession session) {
        
        if (session.getAttribute("loggedInUser") == null) {
            return "redirect:/login";
        }
        
        UserModel user = (UserModel) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
        List<ProductModel> products = productService.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        model.addAttribute("person", user.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(user);
        return "products";
    }
```