# I have tried to create editable table. I have table with seven columns. I want to edit table and submit to controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

problem:
I have tried to retrieve all the data that I have, and then edit column date and/or meal times in the Table.
as shown in the code, I have two methods one for GET, and POST for submitting the form  I want to edit the data.
my problem is I can't deal with getting List. it shows me an error or an empty list.

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/table-of-contents")
    public String showTableOfContents(Model model) {
        transactions = getTableOfContents();
        model.addAttribute("transactionList", transactions);
        return "table_of_contents";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submitTransactions")
    public String updateTableOfContents(@ModelAttribute("transactionList") List<TransactionMealList> transactions) {
      // process of transactions
        return "redirect:/table-of-contents";
    }
```

and front end code:

```
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{table.sequence}"> Number</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{full.name.english}">Full Name</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{date.transaction}">Date</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{breakfast}">Breakfast</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{lunch}">Lunch</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{lunch}">Dinner</th>
                <th class="text-center" th:text="#{restaurants}">Restaurant</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr style="border: #757171 solid 1pt" th:each="transaction, iterStat : *{transactionList}">

                <td th:text="${transaction.employeeHrId} ">123
                </td>
                <td th:text="${transaction.employeeFullName}">Some name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" type="date"
                           th:field="*{transactionList[__${iterStat.index}__].mealDate}" id="validFrom"
                           name="validFrom"
                           style="color: #FFFFFF">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{transactionList[__${iterStat.index}__].isBreakfast}"
                           style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{transactionList[__${iterStat.index}__].isLunch}"
                           style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{transactionList[__${iterStat.index}__].isDinner}"
                           style="width:20px; height:20px;"/>
                </td>
                <td th:text="${transaction.restaurantName}">A
                </td>


                </td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-light" type="button" id="submitButton">Submit</button>

    </form>


</div>
```

Comment: You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76645174/object-not-being-passed-to-html-file-not-being-printed-on-webpage/76647120#76647120)

Answer (score 0):

try using @RequestParam

```
    @PostMapping("/submitTransactions")
public String updateTableOfContents(@RequestParam List<TransactionMealList> transactionList) {
    // Process the updated transactions
    return "redirect:/table-of-contents";
}
```

Comment: it didnt work, 
I found a way to Ajax, but not still have some problems