# I can make tables in the h2 db, but cannot seem to populate it with static data from my data.sql file

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

I am fairly new to spring and the online lecture I am following is a little outdated. I made a very simple html form from where I can add data to a database. I can make the table but cannot populate this table with the static data in the data.sql file. I can however add data to the table using the connected html form.

Entity

```
package com.me.practice.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="location_entity")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String country, st;

    public Location() {

    }

    public Location(String country, String st) {
        this.country = country;
        this.st = st;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getSt() {
        return st;
    }

    public void setSt(String st) {
        this.st = st;
    }

}
```

HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Location</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/new-location/save" method="post" th:object="${loc}">
        <p>Country<input type="text" th:field="${loc.country}"/></p>
        <p>State<input type="text" th:field="${loc.st}"/></p>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Repository interface

```
package com.me.practice.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.me.practice.entity.Location;

public interface LocRepo extends CrudRepository<Location, Long>{

}
```

Controller

```
package com.me.practice.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.me.practice.dao.LocRepo;
import com.me.practice.entity.Location;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/new-location")
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocRepo locRepo;

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newLocation(Model mdl) {
        Location location = new Location();
        mdl.addAttribute("loc", location);
        return "locationForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveLocation(Location location, Model model) {
        locRepo.save(location);
        return "redirect:/new-location/new";
    }

}
```

Main Method

```
package com.me.practice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.me.practice.entity")
public class PracticeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PracticeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Application properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2.console
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath:db/data.sql
```

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO LocationEntity (country, st) VALUES ('Brazil', 'Rio de Janeiro');
INSERT INTO LocationEntity (country, st) VALUES ('USA', 'Texas');
INSERT INTO LocationEntity (country, st) VALUES ('Japan', 'Hokkaido');
```

Answer (score 0):

In `newLocation` function you need to get `Location` entity from repository and check that it has data you want to display on web page eg.

```
Location location = locRepo.getAll();
System.out.println("Country=" + location.getCountry);
```

Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76645174/object-not-being-passed-to-html-file-not-being-printed-on-webpage/76647120#76647120) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data.sql? It should be in the resources folder with application.properties

Edit: You have both hibernate and JDBC initializing your database. You don't need JDBC. You may remove the following from your application.properties:

```
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

You have a lot going on in properties. These properties worked perfectly for me. The database was created if it did not already exist, tables were created and then populated by data.sql:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Comment: The data.sql is in the 'db' folder inside the resources folder. I have specified the path in application properties